# Virus/Trojan detected by CLAMAV

Tags: 14.04, server, malware, antivirus, clamav

[image: VIRUS from a pdf.file]

ClamAV reports finding a virus or trojan. I've never seen this before and I'm not sure what to do. Can anyone advise?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 (not in a virtual machine)

Answer (score 2):

ClamAV is a good program, but sometimes you have to take what it tells you with a grain of salt.

In your particular case, it detects a "PUA" (Possible Unwanted Application) in a PDF file. PUA's are usually "false positives", meaning it's a false hit.

Any time the ClamAV database is updated, there's a higher chance for false positives.

Best thing to do... keep an eye on your ClamAV scans, and see if the error goes away on its own after a few days. If it does go away on its own... it WAS a false positive. If it doesn't go away on its own, delete the file if you don't need it.

Comment: Thank you , I am not sure about this what is the another option for an anti virus and a firewall , or like Malwarebytes for ( WINDOWS) equivalent in linux ( ubuntu )/xubuntu

Comment: ClamAV is probably the most used AV on Ubuntu. GUFW is a good graphic interface for the firewall configuration.

Comment: I will , I was so paranoid when I saw the trojan after the scan on clamAV . I was like really , seriously on my main linux machine

Comment: In the mean time you can *quarantine* (with the eponymous button) files that are suspicious but that you want to keep around in case you still need them or turns out to be a false positive indeed. This will thwart their destructive potential.

Comment: I already deleted the file I am not taking any chances thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the file by clicking delete button. It found a trojen embedded in a pdf. Sounds not safe.

Comment: do I need to worry much about this?

Comment: if it is a single file and the file is unimportant i think no. as @heynnema said sometimes it may give false positives. It is a take your own risk situation.

Comment: No it is not an important its an authorization from an establishment and I filled out the form and send it via email

Comment: Don't take risk.Delete then.  (:

Comment: @DavidFoerster there is a delete button in the sceenshot (: . Aynway i edited the answer.